# How to check progress when uploading a file to QBContent?

Tags: quickblox

We're uploading files to QB Content using QB Content TUploadFile and we used setProgress to check the progress of the upload but we received random values ranging from 0 to 0.5 multiple times.

What is the right way to check the progress of an upload to QB Content?

```
[QBContent TUploadFile:imageData fileName:imageName contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES delegate:self context:(__bridge void*)context];


- (void)setProgress:(float)progress
{
    NSLog(@"progress: %f", progress);
}
```

Comment: can you provide log with progress values